# How to put comma at start of each line where it is required

Tags: linux, shell

Can some one let me know how to modify the follow text

My sample data looks like this 
INPUT file data

```
    P100
    11,1
    91,1
    12,1
    215,1
    215,1
    P101
    1,2
    8,2
    18,2
    99,2
    00,2
    20,2
```

I want to put comma when ever the line dose not have a comma
So my output for the following file should look like

```
    ,P100
    11,1
    91,1
    12,1
    215,1
    215,1
    ,P101
    1,2
    8,2
    18,2
    99,2
    00,2
    20,2
```

Comment: `sed 's/P/,P/' inputfile >outputfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match lines that don't contain `,` and then prepend it:

```
sed '/,/!s/^/,/' infile > outfile
```

The `!` operator means to apply the following operation to lines that don't match the regular expression.